# value of textarea returned empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form that contains a textarea and submit button. and a JS script that takes the value of the textarea.

The issue I'm facing is when I type text into the textarea and hit submit, the textarea value is empty. HOWEVER, if I hard code text into the textarea the hardcoded value is returned. If I erase the hardcoded value and delete the hardcoded value and type in my own, *the hardcoded vale is still returned.*

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="contentForm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" >
    <textarea name ="editor" id="editBox" rows="5" cols="2">type</textarea>
    <p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    function add() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
var message = "start js";
console.log(message);

var contents = $("textarea").val();

if(contents === undefined) {
  console.log("contents undefined");
}
console.log(contents);
var item = {"id":"12", "content": contents};
var obj = JSON.stringify(item);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(obj2.id);
console.log(obj2.content);
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {

 add(); 

});
```

Notice how the textarea above has "type" preloaded. That's the returned value. If I leave it empty, type in my own text in the form and hit submit, the console log shows empty for the value of contents.

I've tried this as well (using textarea id)

```
var contents = $("#editBox").val();
```

I'm assuming the issue lies with POST. Because when I hit enter, the text I entered is replaced with "type" (pre-loaded text).

Can POST interfere with it? How else can I go about retrieving the value?

Comment: @Joe -- `val()` will work fine.

Comment: Pass `event` into your click handler and cancel the default action: `$("#submit").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...}`

Comment: @tymeJV Still same issue

Comment: Change your input type to `button`

Comment: @tymeJV same issue still

Comment: Gahh...this is frusterating man! can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: @tymeJV I mean yeah but I'm relying heavily on the console logs so it wouldn't be a good choice...? right..?

Comment: The code appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/eVmQ9/

Comment: Lets boil it down, on your page, create another textarea and another button, write a simple click handler and grab those contents, does that work?

Comment: @tymeJV here. i changed them to alerts. try to change the 1 to anything else and it still returns 1 http://jsfiddle.net/X94gt/1/

Comment: @schmidt382 maybe a stupid question but how can you tell the value is there? the alerts and console show empty values

Comment: @user2615490 Your fiddle works if you change `text()` to `val()`: http://jsfiddle.net/sCUhn/. Also, `console.log` is fine to use with jsfiddle.

Comment: @JasonP I got it to work somehow...with a combination of removing pre-loaded text and changing .text() to .val()

Comment: textarea is different from input type=text. the value is inner text

Comment: Maybe try using an input field instead of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the actual problem, but something strange I have noticed in past few days. `console.log()` does not work in chrome in few cases like this one. May be it is a firebug bug? Anyways, replaced `console.log()` with `alert` and removed the default value from `textarea`.

Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/eVmQ9/2/

This seems to work on chrome and firefox.